# Angular 8 hot/live reload not work properly

Tags: angular

I have some stressful problem. Angular v8 hot reload is not working properly . My web app UI is broken after I edit little bit e.g edit my text in tag

. So I have to re-run my web app using ng serve to watch what's my web app looks like after I editted.
Affected Package
Angular Material

here is my package I use:

```
{
  "name": "admin-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.801.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~8.2.11",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.4.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.12",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.11",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: before all, restart vscode.

Comment: still not works for me

Comment: You have any outputs / errors in your console ?

Comment: no error in my cmd or console. in cmd it says compiled successful

Comment: it sucessfully detects changes btw